# How can a Discord bot create a hyperlink in a Discord message in an embed or in general?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperlink, discord, discord.js

Today I did a lot of research on hyperlinks and how to use them. But everything I found didn't work as they were probably outdated…

How can my Discord.js bot send a message with a hyperlink? I know I can use `.setTitle("Titel")` and `.setURL("https://...")` to make a link in the embed title, but how can I use these hyperlinks elsewhere in the embed like in a field?

Also, it is possible to create a hyperlink just in a guild channel as a normal user?

Can someone help me in general with hyperlinks, or provide useful documentation which is not outdated?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [Click me](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: yes I do! I tried writing [click me](<url>) in a chat but it didn't worked :(

Comment: You cannot do that as a normal user. Only bots can achieve that in embed messages.

Comment: and how can a bot achieve this?

Comment: You answered your own question a little bit earlier. You can achieve that by using `[TextToShow](URL)`. Note that this does not work in a FieldEmbed title.

Comment: however .addField(["Click me"]("https://stackoverflow.com/"), "txt") doesnt work:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: ["Click me"] is not a function

Comment: The title, as well as the value, must be a string. Example: `.addField("Hello!", "[Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com)")`.

Comment: as it was said, you cannot - discussion [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038398572-Hyperlink-Markdown)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Jakye is right. Only bots can achieve this (but not in field titles, beware). Just do `[link  text here](url here)`.

```js
"Track cases globally, or in a country, by supplying 2-letter [country codes](https://countrycode.org/)."
```

This embed description results in:

[image: this embed description]

this in the embed. Clicking on it directs you to countrycode.org.
Using `.addField()`:

```js
yourEmbed.addField("Title here, no hyperlinks allowed", "Main text here, so you can put a hyperlink here [like so.](https://example.com)");
```

If you want a bot's message to just be a hyperlink, you need to make an embed, and only set the description, hyperlinking as shown above. (you can set the embed color if you want too of course)

Comment: Only works for http and https links.

Comment: I tried, `await channel.send("Track cases globally, or in a country, by supplying 2-letter [country codes](https://countrycode.org/).")` but the text `[country codes](https://countrycode.org/)` appears in the channel instead of the hyperlink. Should I be passing it to another function or has this behaviour changed in Discord?

Comment: @AlexBooker you need to use the MessageEmbed method. Look at [this page](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)

Comment: Could you help me with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74931125/3995261)? (links outside embed, in the main message)